# Accessing Struts2 Properties in Included JSPs

Tags: jsp, properties, struts2, include, action

I want to access Struts2 Action bean properties in included jsp files of my main jsp

Main.jsp [where I can access Action Bean]

```
<s:if test="%{assignedProductBean.productCode =='NOMADIC'}">
   //SOMETHING HERE
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="%{assignedProductBean.productCode =='MOBILE'}">
  //SOMETHING 2 HERE
</s:elseif>
```

This is getting displayed correctly. But I moved this part to sub.jsp

Sub.jsp

```
<s:if test="%{assignedProductBean.productCode =='NOMADIC'}">
   //SOMETHING HERE
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="%{assignedProductBean.productCode =='MOBILE'}">
  //SOMETHING 2 HERE
</s:elseif>
```

Main.jsp

```
<s:include value="./Sub.jsp" />
```

Now I am not getting desired result. No matter whatever is the 'productCode' Something Here is always showed.

What's the exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. I forgot to add

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
```

in my Sub.jsp.

Now It's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use s:include, i think you must add parameters.

```
<s:include value="Sub.jsp">
    <s:param name="param1" value="value2" />
    <s:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</s:include>
```

But I prefer to use

```
<jsp:include page='Sub.jsp'/>
```

so I don't have to send parameters.